# No funcionan mis etiquetas PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy programando en PHP una funcion paa conectarme a la BD mysql , pero creo que el sistema no me esta reconociendo las lineas php.
Porque ya he probado incluso con un simple "holaMundo.php" y no lo reconoce.
Precisar que tengo las tags activadas ,adjunto una captura del codigo que estoy trabajando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me sale este error al enviar al navegador.
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in C:\wamp\www\SistemaWeb\conexion.php on line 23
Call Stack

La linea a la que hace referencia es : 
public function ejecutar()

Comment: Creo que tienes un problema con las llaves , la llave que abres en la funcion del constructor no la cierras en el lugar adecuado. Debes cerrarla antes de la siguiente funcion (ejecutar)

Answer (score 2):

Tienes una funcion dentro del constructor de la clase declarada como `public` y eso no es posible ya que todo lo que esta dentro de una funcion es de ambito privado:

```
class Conexion
{
   public function __construct()
   {
      // error aqui, ejecutar siempre sera privado
      public function ejecutar()
      {
         //...  
      }
   }
}
```

Elimina el modificador `public` de la función para que te funcione:

```
class Conexion
{
   public function __construct()
   {

      function ejecutar()
      {
         //...  
      }
   }
}
```

Pero lo que probablemente quieres es acceder al metodo `ejecutar` por medio a la instancia, así que saca la declaración del método fuera del constructor:

```
class Conexion
{
   public function __construct()
   {

   }

    // declarada fuera del constructor
    public function ejecutar()
    {
         //...  
    }
}
```